# Insert password in ssh using python script

Tags: python, ssh

I need to run a Python script which will get the password from the user and login into the specific box using SSH.

```
password = getpass.getpass('password:')
...
...
command='ssh' + ' ' + "IPname"

p = subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True,stdout=PIPE).communicate(password)[0]
```

But the above script is not working and still it is looking for password.

Comment: Is IPname a variable that you've accidentally quoted?

Comment: you can use `pyexpect` to send the password when the process expects it. You could also just avoid using passwords and use `public key authentification`.

Comment: Don't do this. Use public keys to authenticate. It's a bad idea to hard-code passwords in scripts.

Comment: yes but i'm getting password from user and the script for just internal purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Use [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) like so, because you cannot use password authentication with subprocess, you would have to create and alias and do `ssh somealias`. Paramiko makes it easy to do the authentication without setting up an alias:

```
password = getpass.getpass()

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('some.host.com', username=username, password=password)
```

Or you could use a public key with paramiko as well:

```
pathToKey = "/some/path/here"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('some.host.com', username=username, key_filename=pathToKey)
```

Comment: You can ssh with subprocess, but I haven't tried/wouldn't want to try to do an interactive shell that way, but if you just want to execute a command on the remote system you can definitely use `ssh` with subprocess

Comment: @EricRenouf you can't use it if its a password authentication, you would have to set up an ssh alias and do `ssh somealias`

Comment: Or use something like `sshpass` around it, but I just wanted to clarify your statement "you cannot ssh using subprocess"

Comment: i need alternative of paramiko. could you pls more specific.